# Is there any way to control which disk is hd0 and which is hd1 and so on?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I have an ASUS H110M-K mobo.  It has 4 SATA ports labeled 1-4.  I put my OS disk into the SATA port labeled "SATA 1".  I got all my GRUB2 multi-booting working referring to hd0.  Then when I put a big data disk in the port labeled "SATA 2".  Of course the unthinkable happened.  Now the data disk is hd0 and the OS disk is hd1.  I don't want to just swap the cables around without knowing the methodology or standard, or if I can control it in some kind of setting.

Is there a standard about which disk gets which hd#?  Is it settable on any or some mobos?

I'm thrilled that Linux will assign sda = hd0, and so on, but that is not what I'm asking.  I want to set which physical disk is hd0.  Or I want to know if there are any rules about how these positions are allocated.